# Chrome PDF viewer with markup options

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extensions, print-to-pdf

I still prefer Google Chrome over Microsoft Edge. One thing I like better in Edge is its PDF editing features and being able to highlight text. Is there any way to have this functionality in the default Chrome PDF viewer, e.g. when downloading a PDF file?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend : Kami Extension for Google Chrome :
Offered by: kamihq.com

It has all the features that you want : editing features and being able to highlight text.

Here's the link : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kami-for-google-chrome/ecnphlgnajanjnkcmbpancdjoidceilk?hl=en-GB ;

but you may prefer to search for it in the Chrome Extensions Web Store itself.

You could make it the default PDF viewer in Chrome. It's a very useful extension.

If you install into Chrome the kami extension then you have a choice when you open a pdf file. You are given the options which application you want to open it with ; I prefer to just choose "Drive PDF Viewer" or "Kami" but you could also choose to set it as the default pdf viewer.

Comment: I checked it out but it seems very complex and I did not find a way to make it the default PDF viewer directly. Any alternatives or easy way to make it the default PDF viewer in Chrome and not use cloud services but local files?

Comment: You could make it the default PDF viewer in Chrome. It's a very useful extension. (I wonder who's doing the downvoting of my answer ?) Chrome does have it's own PDF viewer if you like. If you want editing and highlighting, kami extension is the best.

Comment: So _how_ do you make it the default? How do you use it?

Comment: @gronostaj when you open a pdf file you are given the options which application you want to open it with ; i prefer to just choose "Drive PDF Viewer" or "Kami" but you could also choose to set it as the default pdf viewer.

Comment: Wasn't the default behavior to open the PDF in the built-in viewer without asking?

Comment: @gronostaj if you install into Chrome the kami extension then you have a choice.